# How to change two variables by YES/NO MessageBox in VBScript?

Tags: variables, vbscript, messagebox

I need to change this by a YES/NO messagebox.

- **Yes:**

  ```
  For i = 90 To UBound(arrTemp) - 189 'WindowsXP
  ```
- **No:**

  ```
  For i = 510 To UBound(arrTemp) - 870 'Windows10
  ```

My script:

```
Dim i
Dim result
result = MsgBox("[YES] Windows10" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "[NO] WindowsXP", _
         vbYesNo Or vbQuestion, "Select your Windows OS:")
If result = vbYes Then
    i = "90"
Else
    i = "510"
End If
```

How do I change both variables for YES and NO?

Comment: It's unclear what you want, please give the desired result

Comment: When i select YES i want "for i =" change to "90 To UBound(arrTemp) - 189" and NO selected "for i=" to "510 To UBound(arrTemp) - 870"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are close. You just need a couple more variables, besides `i`, since that is the one you are using in your for loop:

```
Dim i
Dim minI
Dim difference
Dim result

'prompt user for OS
result = MsgBox("[YES] Windows10" & VbCrLf & VbCrLf & "[NO] WindowsXP", _
    vbyesno or vbquestion, "Select your Windows OS:")

'change some variables depending on user answer
If result = vbyes Then
    minI=90
    difference = 189
Else
    minI=510
    difference = 870
End If

'Do your loop based on variables.
For i = minI to UBound(arrTemp) - difference

Next i
```

The only other thing is to not set you numeric variables with quotes around them.